# chrome extension download the audio from google translate

Tags: chrome

How to extract audio file/stream from https://translate.google.com/?

I've tried [Audio Downloader Prime](https://mybrowseraddon.com/audio-prime.html), which does detect the audio. Although I can't see the options to download the file to my disk.

Is there this kind of extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested with [**Video DownloadHelper**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-downloadhelper/lmjnegcaeklhafolokijcfjliaokphfk) and it seems to be able to do the job.

I played the audio on the page, then in the extension presses the menu arrow for this audio and copied the URL, opened the URL in the browser and it opened as a direct/downloadable audio.